# smooth function as a sum of rect or tri functions

Tags: sequences-and-series, functions

At the beginning it looks to me easy but i am cannot find a mathematical prove for this.
I am trying to prove that smooth function cannot be written as a sum of rect functions (or tri functions)

for example let say that f(x) is a smooth function i want to prove that it cannot be written as:

$ f\left(x\right)\:=\:\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left(a_n\:rect\left(n\cdot \:g\left(x\right)\right)\right)$

and the same for the tri function:

$ f\left(x\right)\:=\:\sum _{n=0}^{\infty }\left(a_n\:tri\left(n\cdot \:g\left(x\right)\right)\right)$

Thanks

edit:

The definition of the rect and tri functions:

[Rectangular function:](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangular_function):
$\operatorname{rect}(t) = \Pi(t) = \begin{cases}
 0 & \text{if } |t| > \frac{1}{2}, \\
 \frac{1}{2} & \text{if } |t| = \frac{1}{2}, \\
 1 & \text{if } |t| < \frac{1}{2}.
\end{cases}$

[Triangular_function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangular_function): 
$\begin{align}
\operatorname{tri}(x) = \Lambda(x) \ &\overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{}}{=} \ \max(1 - |x|, 0) \\
   &= \begin{cases}
      1 - |x| \qquad & |x| < 1 \\
      0       \qquad & \mathrm{otherwise} \\
      \end{cases}
\end{align}$

Comment: I tried to prove it in the Fourier domain and use the Support of them and say that the support of the Fourier transform of rect is not finite but it is not enough.
also i go to Gibbs phenomenon but it prove that a rect functions cannot be sum of smooth function